# How common is it for women in their 20's to have a BRCA gene test conducted?

Tags: heredity, brca-gene-test

**If women in their 20's do have concerns or family history of having breast cancer, can they request to have the brca-gene-test done??**

**How rare is it for women that young to ask for that? Or is it only in special circumstances where doctors suspect it that doctors make the referral for the brca gene test?**

*I'm not worried about me as I'm fairly certain breast cancer doesn't run in my family -- I think it's just coincidental my grandmothers on either side of the family battled breast cancer late in their lives (my mother is currently in her 60's and doesn't have breast cancer).  **I'm just curious who is tested for brca gene mutations and how medical practitioners make that decision.***

Comment: I guess the testing frequency and the availability if statistics might differ in different countries.